# How to make Docker restart a Container after a period of time?

Tags: node.js, automation, scheduled-tasks, dockerfile, headless

How to restart a Node JS application running inside a docker container after a period of time without user input (Automated)?

I have a Docker Container with an application whose underlying architecture showed to hang once in a while. The idea is to simply restart the application after a period of time. This should all happen automated. Consider the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:6.11.1
ENV HOME=/usr/src/app/
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p $HOME
WORKDIR $HOME
COPY npm-shrinkwrap.json $HOME
RUN npm install
# Bundle app source
COPY . $HOME
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

After `npm start` the application either was successfull or not. In most cases it runs successull. So for the other cases I would like to simply restart the whole application after a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

**Install Node cron**

```
$ npm install --save node-cron
```

**Import node-cron and schedule a task:**
 var cron = require('node-cron');

```
cron.schedule('* * * * *', function(){
  console.log('running a task every minute');
});
```

Comment: Hello as the error is unpredictable I will try it but would this work even if the application hangs? Node application won't do anything anymore. I would prefer a solution where you tell Docker by script to restart the full container. But I will tell if it solved the problem.

Comment: In that case you need to use process manager which will provide you UPSTART,SystemMD, Supervisor or Restart Policy

Comment: I used a bash script to solve the problem. Works flawless! But the process manager started my journey to the solution so thanks for your input.

Comment: Welcome. I am trying to learn DevOps these days. So Started looking into problems of other. it will be helpful If you post the answer here as well

Comment: Done. The solution is 30 minutes old and will be improved as by now it freezes and doesn't give much feedback but in general that is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the following from [ivanvanderbyl](https://github.com/ivanvanderbyl/docker-nightmare).

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint", "node", "--harmony-async-await"]
```

And the official documentation on [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint), [Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/) and reading through a bunch of Bash tutorials I came up with the following solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " # Starting Scraper"
node index.js -D
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start node: $status"
  exit $status
fi
echo " # Init Restart-Routine. Beware, console will freeze!"
while :
do
  echo "[1]/[4] Sleep"
  sleep 5
  echo "[2]/[4] Kill node process"
  pkill -f "node index.js"
  echo "[3]/[4] Sleep 2 seconds to make sure everything is down"
  sleep 2
  echo "[4]/[4] Start NodeJS"
  node index.js
done
```

The final product does the following: When I start Docker it starts my node application and after a period of time it kills the node process BUT NOT the docker process and restarts it. Exactly what I was looking for.